# Controller not returning json data to the view in asp.net MVC Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am facing issue while returning Json values to View. I don't know why it is happening may be issue with JQuery. Below is my code for reference. Its not executing the success parameter of AJAX.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var $edituserform = $("#edituserform");

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#userList').DataTable();
});

function updateuser(id)
{
    var myUrl = '@Url.Action("EditUser", "Admin")';
    //var myUrl = '/Admin/EditUser?Id=' + id;
    alert(id)
    $.ajax({
        url: myUrl,
        type: 'GET',
        data: {Id:id},
        dataType: 'json',
        sucess: function (result) {
            alert('inside success')
            //$edituserform.html(result.partialView);
            $edituserform.load(result);
        }
    })
}
```

---- Controller ----

```
        public ActionResult EditUser(int Id)
    {
        try
        {
            var objUser = objUserLogic.GetUserById(Id);

            //return Json(new { partialView = MvcHelper.RenderPartialView(this, "_EditUser", objUser, null) }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);   //tried this commented code first
            return PartialView("_EditUser", objUser);
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
                            return View("ViewUsers");
        }

    }
```

Comment: In what way did the commented out solution not work?

Comment: Your dataType in your js is `'josn'` but should be `'json'`

Comment: @Corporalis changed 'josn' to 'json' but still not working...

Comment: @David its not passing the json values to Ajax.

Comment: Do you reach the server? What is the response?

Comment: @David response showing correct... But its not displaying the result in view... I am having the same problem with other functions too... I am not able to return values to ajax functions...

Comment: Does the alert show up? The value of `$edituserform` is assigned outside of `DOMReady`, are you sure that it refers to an object? Try `alert($edituserform.length)`. Also, `.load` is probably not the method you're looking for. What are you trying to do? `.html` still seems like the better option.

Comment: Your controller method returns html (a view), not json, so it needs to be `dataType: 'html',` (or just omit the `dataType` option and the ajax method will work it out). And `$edituserform.load(result);` makes no sense - it would need to be `$edituserform.html(result);`

Comment: @Stephen still no result.... Tried your recommended solutions... Nothing is happening...

Comment: @David alert('inside success') is not showing up.... means its not firing 'success:' option. I changed 'load' to $edituserform..html(result) but still giving error...

Comment: Then what error are you getting in the browser console. I can only assume the code in the view is throwing an exception

Comment: @StephenMuecke Its returning Json but not in AJAX. Its rendering plain Json file in the browser.

Comment: The code you have shown does nit return json - its returning a view. Add there is no way the javascript you have shown could redirect (that could only happen if you were making a normal submit). You need to show your real code.

Comment: @StephenMuecke sorry I was telling about commented json value. the line 'return PartialView("_EditUser", objUser);' returning nothing... Instead of passing Partial If I return View then its working fine. But I want to work with Ajax so I was returning Json value

Answer (score 0):

A `PartialView` is not JSON, which you're expecting. Change `dataType` to `text/html` or return a `JsonResult`, i.e. `Json( someModel )`

Comment: No luck... Tried this but still no result.

Answer (score 0):

Controller Method

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult EditUser(int dil)
{
   var objUser = objUserLogic.GetUserById(Id);
   var jsonparse= objUser
                 .Select(x => new  //This is trick that prepare json array
                 {
                       name=x.name, 
                       Id=x.Id
                 });
        return Json(jsonparse, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Ajax Method

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/controllerName/getkat",
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: { Id: xxx},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                //Parse Response
                $.each(data, function (i, state) {
                    $('<option>', {
                        value: state.Id
                    }).html(state.name).appendTo($select);
                });
            }
        },
        complete: function () {
        },
        error: function () {
        }
    });
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but my issue is Json values are not returning to AJAX.

Comment: Json values are not return to ajax? That mean your ajax request to code behind method and that method not response values? You might debug the code you have step by step. I suggest you to put console.log("here") in the success section of your ajax method and also before send too. Than you may catch the issue where is stuck.